# Why RowSetSharing for temp table does not work inside stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, sqlperformance

Here is an example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #t
(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ss varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #t (ss)
    SELECT name FROM master.dbo.spt_values

DELETE FROM #t
```

Run it and check wait stats:

```sql
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats WHERE session_id = <spid>
```

```
session_id wait_type                      waiting_tasks_count  wait_time_ms         max_wait_time_ms     signal_wait_time_ms
---------- ------------------------------ -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
116        SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD            2                    0                    0                    0
116        MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT          125                  0                    0                    0
```

Now put the same code inside stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.tp_test_temp_latches
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #t
    (
        id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
        ss varchar(50)
    )

    INSERT INTO #t (ss)
        SELECT name FROM master.dbo.spt_values

    DELETE FROM #t
END
```

Run it and check wait stats again.
We will see a lot of pagelatch_ex waits:

```
session_id wait_type                     waiting_tasks_count  wait_time_ms         max_wait_time_ms     signal_wait_time_ms
---------- ----------------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
1043       PAGELATCH_EX                  2537                 5                    0                    3
1043       SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD           2                    0                    0                    0
1043       MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT         132                  1                    0                    0
```

I checked execution plan with DBCC TRACEON (8666).
First example shows RowSetSharing = 1.
Second example shows RowSetSharing = 0.

I have some big stored procedures which works a lot with temp tables in my current project. I would like to take benefit from rowset sharing but I can't. I founded Paul White blog post where he describes how he turn off rowset sharing with OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 8746): [changes-to-a-writable-partition-may-fail](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/sql-plan/changes-to-a-writable-partition-may-fail)

Is there any option for turning it on? Or any other possibility?

**UPDATE 05/03/2018**

I have found one workaround.
To eliminate excesive PAGELATCH_EX waits we could turn on "Table spool" by using trace flag 8692:

```
DELETE FROM #t
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 8692)
```

This option allows to read all needed rows and only than to update/delete them. So we separate read/write operations. This technique eliminates PAGELATCH_EX waits and drops logical reads almost twice. This is still far from using temp table outside stored procedure. But it is twice faster than not using this option.

**UPDATE 07/03/2018**

Further investigation leaded me to one more workaround (more efficient):

```
DELETE t FROM (SELECT TOP (10000000) * FROM #t ORDER BY IIF(id = 0, 0, id)) t
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

Sort operator works in memory instead in tempdb like "table spool" does.

Comment: There's a simpler workaround: `EXEC ('DELETE FROM #t')`. Of course, dynamic SQL isn't attractive as a general solution. This suggests the way stored procedure compilation works has something to do with it. (No, `OPTION RECOMPILE` has no effect.)

Comment: **@Jeroen Mostert**, Thanks. It work like a charm. But I have stored procedures which works a lot with temp tables (DELETE/UPDATE). I can't just put every statement inside EXEC. But any way, thank you for this workaround. I can use it in some "heavy" places.

Comment: You could try asking this on https://dba.stackexchange.com/